# Keep is as as is?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I saw a sentence on an app, AnkiPro, and was not sure about something. The sentence went like "Should we give a big hand to each beauty contestant **is as** she is introduced, or should we wait until all the introductions are finished?". I don't think "is" is necessary before "as". Is it more idiomatic with "is" attached to "as" or is "is as" a common phrase used? I know there is an expression "as is".

Comment: The 'is' is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "is as" in the sentence is wrong and sounds very unnatural. The correct sentence is:

"Should we give a big hand to each beauty contestant as she is introduced, or should we wait until all the introductions are finished?"